# Matplotlib plot_date x-axis labels off by days and partially missing

Tags: matplotlib

I've got a script that transforms query results into a timeseries visualization using matplotlib's `plot_date()` function. It used to work well, but at some point (not really sure why) the dates started acting up.

Here's the underlying data:

```
0 = {list} <type 'list'>: [u'2017-07-03', 427]
1 = {list} <type 'list'>: [u'2017-07-10', 201]
2 = {list} <type 'list'>: [u'2017-07-17', 594]
3 = {list} <type 'list'>: [u'2017-07-24', 525]
4 = {list} <type 'list'>: [u'2017-07-31', 239]
5 = {list} <type 'list'>: [u'2017-08-07', 437]
```

Here's the code to generate the graph:

```
def generate_timeseries(values, **kwargs):
    x_values = []
    y_values = []
    for item in values['rows']:
        x_values.append(datetime.strptime(item[0], "%Y-%m-%d"))
        y_values.append(item[1])

    # General Figure
    figure = plt.figure()
    low = min(y_values)
    high = max(y_values)
    plt.ylim([0, math.ceil(high + 0.4 * (high - low))])
    figure.set_size_inches(kwargs['chart_size'][0], kwargs['chart_size'][1], forward=True)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)

    # General Axis
    axis = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    axis.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    axis.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

    # Y-Axis
    axis.get_yaxis().tick_left()
    axis.yaxis.label.set_color('gray')
    axis.yaxis.grid()
    if kwargs['show_axis_labels']:
        axis.set_ylabel(kwargs['y_label'])

    # X-Axis
    axis.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
    axis.xaxis.label.set_color('gray')
    if kwargs['show_axis_labels']:
        axis.set_xlabel(kwargs['x_label'])
    axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter(kwargs.get('date_format', '%Y-%m-%d')))

    plt.plot_date(x_values,
                  y_values,
                  linestyle='-',
                  color=kwargs['palette'][0],
                  marker='o' if kwargs['marker'] else None,
                  linewidth=1.6,
                  clip_on=False)

    if kwargs['show_datapoint_labels']:
        for xy_comb in zip(x_values, y_values):
            axis.annotate('{}'.format(xy_comb[1]), xy_comb,
                          xycoords='data',
                          xytext=(2, 10),
                          textcoords='offset points')

    if kwargs['show_legend']:
        plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05), fancybox=True, fontsize=6)

    return plt
```

And last but not least, here's how the graph turns out:
[image]

Notice that:

1. There are 6 data points, but only 5 date labels visible
2. There seems to be a 5 day shift in the dates

I've verified the input before the `plot_date()` function; I've verified the timezones on the data (which would not explain a 5 day shift, but still); I've tried different variations of formatting and manipulating the dates based on the suggestions [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html), but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Has anyone experienced similar issues or can spot the problem in my code? I've spent several hours trying to debug/research and feel like I've gotten no where so far.

[Matplotlib V2.0.2; Python 2.7.13]

Comment: What exactly *is* the issue? The plot you show seems to be perfectly correct and the labels are correctly positionned. If you want to position your labels at different locations, you need to tell exactly where you want to have them.

Comment: As I originally wrote - I'm missing 1 label, and the others are not aligned with the data points (not in place and not in date)

Comment: So you want to have exactly one label at the position of each datapoint, and no labels at positions not occupied by datapoints? (I guess it's clear that this requirement is not the default one, since it would produce 200 labels if 200 points are plotted and that sure is undesired.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the tick locations to exactly the dates that the data points are located at, you need to use a Locator as well as a Formatter.

The locator should be a `matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator` which sets the locations according to the input data. The formatter can be any `matplotlib.dates` formatter.

```
data = [[u'2017-07-03', 427],
        [u'2017-07-10', 201],
        [u'2017-07-17', 594],
        [u'2017-07-24', 525],
        [u'2017-07-31', 239],
        [u'2017-08-07', 437]]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
import matplotlib.ticker
import datetime

x,y = zip(*data)
f = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')
x = list(map(f, x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

loc = matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(matplotlib.dates.date2num(x) )
fmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should make it clear that there is no problem with `plot_date`. I think the issue is that you expected the starting ticks to be aligned with your starting data, rather than aligned along equal intervals that enclose your data. (edit: I do see that your data are spaced weekly). You can manipulate the xtick locations to your liking with the `Locator` subclasses.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy

old_data = [
    ['2017-07-03', 427],
    ['2017-07-10', 201],
    ['2017-07-17', 594],
    ['2017-07-24', 525],
    ['2017-07-31', 239],
    ['2017-08-07', 437],
]

data = []
for i in old_data:
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(i[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
    data.append([d,i[1]])

data = numpy.array(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))
locator = mpl.dates.DayLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.grid(True)

_=ax.plot_date(data[:,0], data[:,1],linestyle='-')
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(270)
# fig.savefig("date_plot.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the method it worked for me is

`plt.figure(dpi=100,tight_layout= True)`

`tight_layout` is by default `False`, but when you set it to `True`, it can ease your work.